# flash audio player volume setting in action script 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder

i am creating a audio flash player and i want to set the volume of the sound to 0 and then again to 60. Means i want to toggle between these values on a single button click. I searched but didn't found appropriate way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private var _volumeMin : Number = 0;
private var _volumeMax : Number = 60;

public function toggleVolume() : void
{
    if(_volume == _volumeMax)
    {
          _volume = _volumeMin;
    }
    else
    {
        _volume = _volumeMax;
    }

    // update real sound here
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. but tell me 1 thing please _volume is sound from sound channel ?

Comment: Volume is a private variabel. Just apply it to your sound/soundchannel at the end of the function.